# Cannot init TypeORM with oracledb

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I'm trying to init a typerorm project and I get this error when running the typeorm init --database oracle this is the console error I get:

```
    Project created inside current directory.
    Error during project initialization:
    npm WARN deprecated oracledb@1.13.1: Update to node-oracledb 5
    npm ERR! code 1
    npm ERR! path E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb
    npm ERR! command failed
    npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
    npm ERR! Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "-m" switch.
    npm ERR!   njsOracle.cpp
    npm ERR! E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\nan\nan_maybe_43_inl.h(112,15): error C2039: 'ForceSet': is not a member of 'v8::Object' [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR! C:\Users\memar\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\17.4.0\include\node\v8-value-serializer.h(21): message : see declaration of 'v8::Object' [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR! E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\nan\nan_converters_43_inl.h(22,1): error C2664: 'v8::Local<v8::Boolean> v8::Value::ToBoolean(v8::Isolate *) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'v8::Local<v8::Context>' to 'v8::Isolate *' [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR! E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\nan\nan_converters_43_inl.h(22,1): message : No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR! C:\Users\memar\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\17.4.0\include\node\v8-value.h(398,18): message : see declaration of 'v8::Value::ToBoolean' [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR! E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\nan\nan_converters_43_inl.h(40,1): error C2664: 'bool v8::Value::BooleanValue(v8::Isolate *) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'v8::Local<v8::Context>' to 'v8::Isolate *' [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR! E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\nan\nan_converters_43_inl.h(40,1): message : No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR! C:\Users\memar\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\17.4.0\include\node\v8-value.h(408,8): message : see declaration of 'v8::Value::BooleanValue' [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR! E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\nan\nan_implementation_12_inl.h(103,37): error C2664: 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Function> v8::Function::New(v8::Local<v8::Context>,v8::FunctionCallback,v8::Local<v8::Value>,int,v8::ConstructorBehavior,v8::SideEffectType)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'v8::Isolate *' to 'v8::Local<v8::Context>' [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR! E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\nan\nan_implementation_12_inl.h(105,32): message : No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR! C:\Users\memar\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\17.4.0\include\node\v8-function.h(31,31): message : see declaration of 'v8::Function::New' [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR! E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\nan\nan_implementation_12_inl.h(337,37): error C2660: 'v8::StringObject::New': function does not take 1 arguments [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR! C:\Users\memar\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\17.4.0\include\node\v8-primitive-object.h(81,23): message : see declaration of 'v8::StringObject::New' [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR! E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\nan\nan_implementation_12_inl.h(337,60): error C2059: syntax error: ')' [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR! E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\nan\nan.h(832,18): warning C4996: 'node::MakeCallback': was declared deprecated [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR! E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\nan\nan.h(847,18): warning C4996: 'node::MakeCallback': was declared deprecated [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR! E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\nan\nan.h(862,18): warning C4996: 'node::MakeCallback': was declared deprecated [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR! E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\nan\nan.h(909,1): error C2660: 'v8::Value::ToString': function does not take 0 arguments [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR! C:\Users\memar\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\17.4.0\include\node\v8-value.h(360,44): message : see declaration of 'v8::Value::ToString' [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR! E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\nan\nan.h(919,1): error C2664: 'int v8::String::WriteUtf8(v8::Isolate *,char *,int,int *,int) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'char *' to 'v8::Isolate *' [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR! E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\nan\nan.h(919,37): message : Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR! C:\Users\memar\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\17.4.0\include\node\v8-primitive.h(192,7): message : see declaration of 'v8::String::WriteUtf8' [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR! E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1471,31): warning C4996: 'node::MakeCallback': was declared deprecated [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR! E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1531,1): error C2661: 'v8::Object::Set': no overloaded function takes 2 arguments [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR! E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1537,1): error C2661: 'v8::Object::Set': no overloaded function takes 2 arguments [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR! E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1543,1): error C2661: 'v8::Object::Set': no overloaded function takes 2 arguments [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR! E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1549,1): error C2661: 'v8::Object::Get': no overloaded function takes 1 arguments [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR! E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1548,17): error C2672: 'Nan::EscapableHandleScope::Escape': no matching overloaded function found [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR! E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1555,1): error C2661: 'v8::Object::Get': no overloaded function takes 1 arguments [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR! E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1555,17): error C2672: 'Nan::EscapableHandleScope::Escape': no matching overloaded function found [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR! E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1560,1): error C2661: 'v8::Object::Get': no overloaded function takes 1 arguments [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR! E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1560,17): error C2672: 'Nan::EscapableHandleScope::Escape': no matching overloaded function found [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR! E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\nan\nan_object_wrap.h(24,5): error C2039: 'IsNearDeath': is not a member of 'Nan::Persistent<v8::Object,v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>>' [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR!           with
    npm ERR!           [
    npm ERR!               T=v8::Object
    npm ERR!           ]
    npm ERR! E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1572): message : see declaration of 'Nan::Persistent<v8::Object,v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>>' [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR!           with
    npm ERR!           [
    npm ERR!               T=v8::Object
    npm ERR!           ]
    npm ERR! E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\nan\nan_object_wrap.h(67,18): error C2039: 'MarkIndependent': is not a member of 'Nan::Persistent<v8::Object,v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>>' [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR!           with
    npm ERR!           [
    npm ERR!               T=v8::Object
    npm ERR!           ]
    npm ERR! E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1572): message : see declaration of 'Nan::Persistent<v8::Object,v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>>' [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR!           with
    npm ERR!           [
    npm ERR!               T=v8::Object
    npm ERR!           ]
    npm ERR! E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\nan\nan_object_wrap.h(124,5): error C2039: 'IsNearDeath': is not a member of 'Nan::Persistent<v8::Object,v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>>' [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR!           with
    npm ERR!           [
    npm ERR!               T=v8::Object
    npm ERR!           ]
    npm ERR! E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1572): message : see declaration of 'Nan::Persistent<v8::Object,v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>>' [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR!           with
    npm ERR!           [
    npm ERR!               T=v8::Object
    npm ERR!           ]
    npm ERR! E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\src\dpi\include\dpiLob.h(34,11): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'oci.h': No such file or directory [E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj]
    npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
    npm ERR! gyp info using node@17.4.0 | win32 | x64
    npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.10 found at "C:\Users\memar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe"
    npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2019 (16.11.32106.194) found at:
    npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community"
    npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Users\memar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'E:\\Github\\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\\backend\\node_modules\\oracledb\\build\\config.gypi',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\memar\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\17.4.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\memar\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\17.4.0',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\memar\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\17.4.0\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=E:\\Github\\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\\backend\\node_modules\\oracledb',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'E:\\Github\\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\\backend\\node_modules\\oracledb\\build',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
    npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:520:28)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22000
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd E:\Github\Proyecto-lenguajes-de-bases-de-datos\backend\node_modules\oracledb
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v17.4.0
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\memar\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-02-07T21_01_26_663Z-debug-0.log
```

I did update the dependency version in the package.json file to 5.3.0 and tried to install doing npm install oracledb@5.3.0, I have also the oracle client set in the PATH variable and can connect to the DB from any workbench, Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you get that error after updating the package dependency?  If not, what error did you now get?  If you did get that error, then you didn't update the right thing.  If all else fails, clean up your node_modules directory and start from the beginning.   I ran the quickstart from https://typeorm.io/#/ a couple of weeks back on macOS without problem after I updated the oracledb dependency in package.json.

Comment: Thanks, Chris, just updated the dependencies and got it to work thanks!

Comment: That's great.  FWIW for other readers my ormconfig.json contained (this won't look good wrapped, but I think you'll figure it out): `   "type": "oracle",
   "username": "system",
   "password": "mypassword",
   "connectString": "mymachine.mydomain.com/orclpdb1", ...`